# IBM VS code extension fabric submit Transition error

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I'm going to connect my local **IBM fabric vs code extension** smart contract to **nodeJS**. it's connected successfully and data added successfully. But In the terminal, I show this error

```
 error: [Orderer.js]: sendBroadcast - on error: "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server\n    at Object.exports.createStatusError
```

I'm using the latest version of the **extension** and **docker images** version is **1.4.4**.

here is my **local connection** file :

```
{
    "name": "basic-network",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.example.com"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:17055"
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:17051"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.example.com": {
            "url": "http://localhost:17050",
            "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is **node** function :

```
async function main(){

  try {

    let response;

    const userExists = await wallet.exists(userName);
    if (!userExists) {
        console.log('An identity for the user ' + userName + ' does not exist in the wallet');
        console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
        response.error = 'An identity for the user ' + userName + ' does not exist in the wallet. Register ' + userName + ' first';
    }
    // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
    await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: userName, discovery: gatewayDiscovery });

    console.log('Connected to Fabric gateway.');
    // Connect to our local fabric
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

    console.log('Connected to mychannel. ');

    contract = await network.getContract('mycontract');
    // return callback ( contract );


    await await contract.submitTransaction('product_register', '6','medical','new');
    console.log('Transaction has been submitted');

    // Disconnect from the gateway.
    await gateway.disconnect();

  } 
  catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error processing transaction. ${error}`);
      console.log(error.stack);
      return callback ( error.stack );
  }


}
```

Can anyone take away me from this error?

Thanks.

Comment: I would check to see what or if anything is listening on port 17055 first.

Comment: Thanks david_k, It was my bad. There was the wrong orderer port. Correct one is **17056**.